# No sound after opening the Sound Settings menu

Tags: sound, settings

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After I opened "Sound Settings" menu, I can't hear any sound, It just disappears. Music and video still play but without sound and no concerning-audio error message appears. I was forced to reinstall system in order to hear music again.

Can anybody know what's going on and how to fix it?  Sound Settings window is empty, no sound cards/ports are shown. No play through devices

Comment: What type of computer do you have and what type of sound card do you have (lspci | grep -i "Audio")?

Answer (score 0):

Look on the `sound menu` and make sure audio not `muted`.Run `Ubuntu Software Center` and install `Ubuntu Restricted Extras`.I think this should fix your issue.

Answer (score -2):

I had sound on initial install using an AMD quad core HP PC and after some problems with installing updates and using synaptic and updates sound want missing.
Almost 2 weeks of research and fixes with sudo apt-get commands in terminal using various fixes had no results.
Almost had to re install OS but I did download and burn Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu as well as other Linux O S Distros. So I decided to use the ISO CD Roms to run from CD and check sound settings and files. 
I noticed that my sound settings were dummy settings. NO SOUND. Alsa would not install and I saw no fix until I used:

```
sudo apt-get install NVidea MCP61 driver.
```

I then checked my home folder.

noticed some HTLM or HTM? files at the bottom of the page and deleted 3 script files that looked out of place.

After this I used:

```
sudo apt-get install update
```

after this I followed the suggestion on the terminal page for other fixes -f
I tried to reinstall `synaptic` and went to the Synaptic package program there I noticed that one package was not installed , I tick and install one extra. removed one and reinstalled or upgraded one that had an exclamation mark next to it. Sorry did not pay attention to detail just went with gut feeling and from what I read.

02:30 am I waited to have all the packages install without taking notes so this is a bit sketchy. 03:00 last resort before reinstalling OS I turn PC off go to bed.
The next day I turn PC on and sound works.

```
HDMI/ display port
built-in audio

Headphones
built-in audio

analogue output
builit-in audio
```

recovered in sound settings.

Dummy output gone.

**Note.** while using the CD rom to test sound with Kubuntu ISO DVD only the right speaker tested OK the left did not work, Ubuntu 12.04 same as Lubuntu. Did not try Xubuntu CD?

The package Manager error still exists and while trying to use package manager to install updates and upgrades previously kept giving me error 404, 502 and proxy error. Disabling Firefox proxy settings did not work?

Something else to spend a lot of time on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Clearly you didn't successfully use the command `sudo apt-get install NVidea MCP61 driver` because that's an invalid use of apt-get. Can you please edit your post to include the correct information?

Comment: Oh, and on cleaning up the formatting, I noticed another invalid command: `sudo apt-get install updates`. Giving incorrect commands is actively harmful to the site and to new users. Please either just describe what you did or provide the exact commands (or at least functional equivalents). -1